# POPUP Just once

Tags: jquery

I use this script to open a popup in a form (1st page), it works good BUT after submitting the form it appears again in confirmation page. I want it to appear just once : What parameter should i add to my script ?

Thank you

EDIT :

This code Exists in a page that contains a form (myform.php) when submitting this form an action [myform.php?action=confirmation] is taken, so in that confirmation page - that is a part of the process of (myfom.php) - The popup (timer.html) appears again. i use ./lib/jquery-1.4.4.min.js..

```js
    var $fb_pop = jQuery.noConflict();

    $fb_pop(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout( function(){ $fb_pop.colorbox({href:"./timer/timer.html", iframe:true, innerWidth:"150px", height:"40%", maxHeight:"200px", fixed:true}) }, 5000 );
        $fb_pop(".fb_iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:"150px", height:"40%", maxHeight:"150px", fixed:true }); 
    });
```

Comment: It's unclear what context this code exists in. If it's on every page it'll show up on every page. If you don't want it to appear on a page you either need to (a) not include/run it, or (b) have a flag on the page to indicate whether or not it should be run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer : This code Exists in a page that contains a form (myform.php) when submitting this form an action [myform.php?action=confirmation] is taken, so in that confirmation page - that is a part of the process of (myfom.php) - The popup (timer.html) appears again. i use ./lib/jquery-1.4.4.min.js..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pop up appears again as the page is reloaded by the form's submit action, thereby executing the javascript code in it again. Execute the javascript only when there is no 'action' parameter in the url.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['action'])) { ?>

     var $fb_pop = jQuery.noConflict();

     $fb_pop(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout( function(){ 
           $fb_pop.colorbox({
             href:"./timer/timer.html", 
             iframe:true, 
             innerWidth:"150px", 
             height:"40%", 
             maxHeight:"200px", 
             fixed:true}) 
         }, 5000 );
    $fb_pop(".fb_iframe").colorbox({
       iframe:true, 
       innerWidth:"150px", 
       height:"40%", 
       maxHeight:"150px", fixed:true }); 
    });    

<?php 
} ?>
```

**Edit 1**
Since you are including the html page inside myform.php through the include() function, make a simple check with javascript to see if the URL contains 'action' text.

```
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("action") === -1) {
    // include your script here
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. BUT my code is between <script>...</script> in an HTML file so can't use <?php..

Comment: In which file is the script placed? myform.php itself?

Comment: Thank you for your help.. The script is placed in an HTML file that is included in myform.php the script is between   <head>...</head>

Comment: You meant included like this <?php include('fileOne.html'); ?>

Comment: Updated my answer.